# NuGet.exe pack gives access to the path is denied

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

When I try to pack my MVC project (`NuGet.exe pack`) I get:

```
NuGet.exe : Access to the path '...' is denied.
```

This happens to be the case for all files in the `content` and `script` folder of my MVC solution. If I remove the readonly flag on all these files `NuGet.exe` is able to create the NuGet package.

Why do I have to remove the readonly flag? Is there another way?

I'm using TFS which specify the readonly flag on all files under source control.

I am running:

- NuGet Version: 1.7.30402.9028
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

I'm using the `NuGet.exe` that you get when you install the NuGet package *NuGet.CommandLine* which is located at http://nuget.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine.

Comment: which version of nuget are you running? under which version of VS?

Comment: I have updated question with version information.

Comment: Was there an answer to this? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: No, I use a PowerShell script to remove the readonly flag, then pack.

Answer (score 35):

Apparently, you need to **set `ReadOnly=false`** for the files it accesses

Comment: The link mentions upgrade and uninstall. It also states that it has to do with offline mode. The question is about _packing_ in online mode.

Comment: Hmm, good point, I realize the question is about packing (I had the same issue) maybe we need to open another issue on NuGet regarding this specifically.

Comment: +1 I had similar issue when I was applying packages to projects via "Manage Solution packages". Your solution helped.

Comment: Also putting packages under TFS source control also makes them read-only, which leads to this error.

Answer (score 18):

Try running it as administrator.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this with `nuget restore` after doing a `git clean -fd` with VisualStudio open: the `packages/` directory was marked for deletion, and while several files were deleted, the `packages/` folder itself was not as VisualStudio had the `.nupkg` files open.

Once I closed VisualStudio and re-ran `git clean`, it removed the `packages/` directory and then nuget was able to restore everthing correctly.

Comment: Same. I encountered this after running `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` with VS open.

Comment: Same (dotnet nuget locals all --clear) , but with Rider.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into a similar problem. I attempted to restart Visual Studio, Run as Administrator (Which I always do), Set the folder attributes to ensure the 'Read-Only' flag was off. Regardless, whatever I did, I still encountered the error "access to the path is denied" when updating my Nu-Get packages.

I was able to fix the issue by updating packages one-by-one. Choosing instead to go through each dependency and updating it. Once the dependency was updated I would choose another, sometimes the same error resulted in which case I would choose another until all my packages were successfully updated.

It appears in my case the Nu-Get packages had to be updated in a particular order.

Hope this helps someone out there

Answer (score 2):

In my case something happened when switching branch in git. Everyone lost execute permissions for Nuget.exe.

This blog post helped me: http://mannysiddiqui.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/nuget-access-is-denied-command-existed-with-code-5/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out windows had an update waiting for the next restart. Cleared with no problem after restarting and waiting for the update.

Answer (score 0):

My collegue just got this error, during all "worked on my machine". After some research I found out that the *.nuspec file for some reason wasn't added to the version control.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Restore nuget packages, remove read only permissions from the folder level (for windows). Clean the solution and Build. It will works

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `*.gitattributes` in the git repo root recently modified (incorrectly), so git started to checkout `nuget.exe` on the build server and converted all `LF` to `CRLF` inside, making it non-executable.

Answer (score -2):

Run your Visual Studio with administrator rights.