# After clearing Nuget caches, every Nuget install fails

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

In VS 2017 on up to date Windows10 I have Nuget Package Manager 4.6 installed. I just cleared all my nuget caches and now if I try to add a Nuget to any project, or a build a project that has nuget dependencies, I get download errors.

e.g.

```
Resolving actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3'
Resolved actions to install package 'Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3'
Retrieving package 'Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/12.0.3/newtonsoft.json.12.0.3.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/12.0.3/newtonsoft.json.12.0.3.nupkg 28ms
Installing Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3.
Error downloading 'Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/12.0.3/newtonsoft.json.12.0.3.nupkg'.
```

I cannot see any issues with Nuget.org in my browser on the same machine and now I basically cannot build anything! What could be the problem?

Comment: which windows? nuget turned off TLS1.0/1.1 support. you need TLS 1.2 support: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/

Comment: W10. I'm using the package manager not Powershell though, so I read this as it should work... also it worked earlier today. Clearing the cache caused the problem.

Comment: Aha, seems to be this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582001/nuget-exe-pack-gives-access-to-the-path-is-denied

Comment: Can you access `nuget.org` under Nuget Package Manager UI?

Comment: I found that you use `https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/.........` as `nuget.org` path, please try to use this: `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/` as nuget.org.

Answer (score 3):

> After clearing Nuget caches, every Nuget install fails

You could try the following steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**Suggestions**

**1)** close VS Instance, delete `C:\Users\xxx(current user account)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`

Also, enter your project path, try to delete `.vs` hidden folder of your solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. And then restart VS.

**2)** try to set your `nuget.org` with `http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/`or `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/`.

under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Sources** to test again.

[image]

Make sure that your current agent Internet can access these paths.

**3)** run `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol-bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**--> **Package Manager Console** and then install the package to test again.

**4)** check if there is a firewall policy or other proxy settings that block the nuget installation package.

**5)** try to disable any third party extensions under **Tools**--> **Extensions and Updates** in case some extensions interface it.

**6)** If your VS has any update, please update it.

Comment: suggestion 2 worked to solve my issue with `Install-Package : Failed to retrieve information about 'Newtonsoft.Json' from remote source: 'https://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='Newtonsoft.Json'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'`